# What is the best way to distinguish whether a region is connected or disconnected with background after applying watershed segmentation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, watershed

I have a labeled image after applying watershed segmentation called L shows below. How I can write a function to decide whether a region is connected or disconnected with the background (shows in blue)?
[image: sample picture]

For example: the function should return 1 (connected) for regions: 2 3 5 6 while return 0 (disconnected) for regions: 1 4 7.

Notice that the white thin area is the margin line which labeled as 0, so actually no region is physically connected with other region after watershed segmentation. This is the most tricky part to handle. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can morphologically thicken each segment separately for a few pixels and see if it overlaps with the background segment.

Comment: That's briliant ,thx! @Ozcan